# How to handle compression static resources over https in Quarkus

Tags: https, gzip, quarkus

**Problem**

I want to compress static resources in Quarkus like js, css, and image. I was activated configuration for compression **quarkus.http.enable-compression:true**. It's working perfectly on **HTTP** mode but does not working over https.

**Expected behavior**

Content will be compressed as GZIP over HTTPS

**Actual behavior**

No GZIP compression over HTTPS

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Git pull from [quarkus-demo](https://github.com/Herdi-73/quarkus-demo.git) I made earlier
2. Create certificate for enable SSL in localhost with [mkcert](https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/)
3. Compile with command `mvn clean package -Dquarkus.profile=prod` for running over **HTTPS**. If you want to test over **HTTP** please run with this command `mvn quarkus:dev`
4. Run quarkus app with this command `java -jar target\quarkus-app\quarkus-run.jar`
5. Finally, open your browser to access `https://localhost` or `http://localhost:8080` and then please inspect element to check loaded resources details at **Network** tab

**application.yml**

```
quarkus:
  application:
    version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  http:
    port: 8080
    enable-compression: true
```

**application-prod.yml**

```
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8080
    ssl-port: 443
    ssl:
      certificate:
        file: D:\system\server\localhost.pem
        key-file: D:\system\server\localhost-key.pem
    insecure-requests: redirect
    enable-compression: true
```

**HTTP**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.e96189d0.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
accept-ranges: bytes
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 10 Mar 2022 07:41:46 GMT
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

**HTTPS**

```
Request URL: https://localhost/js/chunk-vendors.e96189d0.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, immutable, max-age=86400
content-length: 880682
content-type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 10 Mar 2022 07:45:07 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 10 Mar 2022 07:45:07 GMT
vary: accept-encoding
```

**FYI : I've tried using vert.x filter but doesn't help :(**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

@ApplicationScoped
public class FilterRegistrator {

    void setUpFilter(@Observes Filters filters) {
        filters.register((rc) -> {
            rc.next();

            if (rc.normalizedPath().matches("^.*\\.(js|css|svg|png)$")) {
                rc.response().headers().add("content-encoding", "gzip");
            }
        }, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the proof ?

Comment: Does your production server use native or is it still in JVM mode?

Comment: @Clement I use native for production server.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil Sure, I've just added response for each environtment.

Comment: I tried with curl ```curl 'http://localhost:8080/css/petclinic.css' -v --head --compressed``` but still can not see gzip , can you put a reproducer to github ? and dont forget to share how to test.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil Thanks for taking time to solve this issue, I really appreciate it. I was added how to reproduce this issue on the Question. I hope it's helpul enough :)

Comment: looks like this is a bug. I wonder is this a vertx bug or quarkus bug. as work around I suggest to use nginx or apache for https and gzip, this is very common in industry.

Comment: Yeah I think this is a bug. I hope someone who is an expert in Quarkus can solve this issue.

Comment: please report https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues let the real team know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved on [Quarkus 2.7.5.Final](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/24287)